# Parse XML to Java Object

Tags: xml, spring-data, castor, spring-oxm

I'm using Spring OXM and Spring data in order to load a dataset.xml and save it into MongoDB using **Repository Populator**.
I'm trying to do that using a **Castor Marshaller** bean:

```
<oxm:castor-marshaller
      id="castorMarshaller"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      mapping-location="classpath:/dataset/mappings/mapping.xml"/>
```

My file dataset.xml looks like:

```
<roles>
  <role id="1234567890" name="Administrator_TEST"/>
  <role id="1234567891" name="User_TEST"/>
</roles>
```

My POJO looks like:

```
public class Role {
private String id;
private String name;

// getters and setters
}
```

This xml makes me understand that I've got a list of ROLES and inside I'm defining each role with 2 fields each one (Each `<role>` represents an object `Role.java`).
Would Castor be able to parse this dataset.xml in a `List<Role>`???
I found in internet that one Java object represents one element inside the XML, that is also the root element.

Can someone help me about this case???

Thanks in advance :-)

mapping.xml

```
<mapping>
  <class name="com.foo.Role">
    <map-to xml="role"/>

    <field name="id" type="string">
      <bind-xml name="id" node="attribute"/>
    </field>

    <field name="name" type="string">
      <bind-xml name="name" node="attribute"/>
    </field>
  </class>
</mapping>
```